# Why c++ is called an object oriented programming language?

Tags: c++

Why c++ is called an object oriented programming language?

Comment: Usually it's called multi-paradigm. OOP is one paradigm it supports.

Comment: Is the 'b' key on your keyboard broken?

Comment: c++ is a hybrid programming language.

Comment: I was referring to the original post before it was edited by David Sykes. The OP wrote: "plz give me answer" ...

Comment: @humbagumba: I completely misunderstood ... deleted my comment ...

Comment: because among many other things, C++ supports some OOP features, and some people think OOP is the only paradigm that matters.

Comment: That's a good question. C++ violates all three parts of the definition of object-orientation, and it is explicitly cited as an example of a not-object-oriented language by the inventor of object-orientation. Therefore, it is clearly not an object-oriented language.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen the [fundamental concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Fundamental_concepts_and_features) of object orientation?

- inheritance
- abstraction
- encapsulation
- polymorphism
- ...
- classes
- instances
- methods
- decoupling

Just compare them to what C++ allows you ([taken from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Objects)):

> [C++] offers classes, which provide the four features commonly present in OO (and some non-OO) languages: abstraction, encapsulation, inheritance, and polymorphism

Comment: @downvoter: please leave a comment - I'd like to know the problem on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Because it deals with 'objects", which are basically in memory representations of a data structure and it's associated behaviours.

You should read a tutorial on objects and object-oriented programming languages for more info.

Answer (score -1):

> why c++ is called oject oriented programming language?

Because it has virtual functions? By the way, C++ isn't [just an Object-Oriented Programming Language](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/oopsla.pdf).

Comment: Why the downvote? C with classes didn't have virtual functions and wasn't considered OO, while C++ was considered OO from the start because it has virtual functions. In my opinion, late binding a.k.a. dynamic polymorphism is the most important ingredient of OO.